# Secure transactions (on or off the internet) with a credit card

Tags: credit-card

## How can I make credit card transactions secure?

I have read about how hopelessly insecure credit cards are, and was wondering if there is a solution.

---

I am in the UK

---

## Some things that I have found, that claim to make transactions secure, but don't.

### Secure Credit cards

These are the opposite of what you would think. This is a way to let the credit card company take your house, if something goes wrong. The bank is securing them self with your house (or other asset).

### Emue:

In Europe there is a product that uses it, Visa CodeSure.

> Users input their card number when purchasing online, flip the card
> over and turn on the screen.
>
> They then input their pin, and a unique one-time-passcode appears on
> the display, which is used by the cardholder to authenticate the
> purchase or payment.

So basically, you hand over the keys, then do some other stuff that may deny you access. Your keys (card number) can still be used on the thousands of sites that don't use this scheme.

Also it seems to be a replacement to using a separate card reader, thus going in the wrong direction to allow a usb reader, and automation.

> Visa CodeSure does away with these card readers and replaces the
> current Verified by Visa system for those using the new card.

It also seems to be increasing the amount of techno-junk.

I think it will reduce fraud, however I don't think it will make transactions secure.

Comment: Questions seeking specific product/service recommendations are off-topic. Sorry.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I am not asking for recommendation. But may be some names, or hints on what to ask for (generic product names).

Comment: Google virtual credit cards and also consider prepaid debit cards.

Comment: related https://security.stackexchange.com/q/28991/7963

Comment: This is an area that is the complete opposite of becoming obsolete. This is an up and coming service. When I asked the question there was nothing. Now there is nearly nothing, but improving. Yes some parts of the answer will involve product listings, and they may grow stale and need editing. However at the current time most of the answer is not product listing.

Comment: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vbciucfe37I (I think everyone assumes that the banks are doing a good job: where are the banks that do this?).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## My ideas

- One time use credit cards.
- Text me on transaction cards.
- Pre-paid cards: limited exposure.
- Secure transaction cards ( I suspect these would be incompatible with the existing system)

## What I have found (I will add more, when I find them)

I am not recommending any. This is just what I have found, in my search.

### Virtual credit cards

e.g.

- https://www.barclaycard.co.uk/business/cards/virtual (UK)
- Privacy.com

### General purpose gift card

e.g.

- visa gift card

### Notify on use

- Some card providers will send a text, when the card is used. The ones I have seen send only if a single purchase is over £25 (so a criminal can make hundreds of purchases of £24.99, without you knowing). They don't seem to understand the idea of “when £25 is spent since the last text”.

### Other

Google virtual credit cards and also consider prepaid debit cards. — @Bob Baerker (comment copied here)